# INSERT statement fails silently in PHP-script, but works at the prompt

Tags: php, postgresql, insert

I have the following table in PostgreSQL 8.4.5:

```
snake=> create table gps (
id bytea check(length(id) = 16),
stamp timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp,
pos point not null);
```

and I'm able to INSERT record into it from psql prompt:

```
snake=> insert into gps (id, pos) values (decode(md5('x'), 'hex'), point(0, 0));
INSERT 0 1
snake=> insert into gps (id, pos) values (decode(md5('x'), 'hex'), point(0, 0));
INSERT 0 1
```

But for some reason INSERT fails in my PHP script listed below and its result is returned as 0. Does anybody please have an idea what is wrong there or how to get more info? I'm surprised that an exception isn't thrown.

```
<?php

$id  = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
$lat = strtr(trim($_REQUEST['lat']), ',', '.');
$lon = strtr(trim($_REQUEST['lon']), ',', '.');

if (preg_match('/^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$/', $id) &&
    preg_match('/^[+-]?[0-9.]+$/', $lat) &&
    preg_match('/^[+-]?[0-9.]+$/', $lon)) {

        try {
                $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=/tmp', 'snake', 'snake');
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $insert = $db->prepare("insert into gps (id, pos) values (decode(?, 'hex'), point(?, ?))");
                $res = $insert->execute($id, $lat, $lon);

                $select = $db->prepare("select encode(id, 'hex') as id, extract('epoch' from stamp) as stamp, pos[0] as lat, pos[1] as lon from gps");
                $select->execute();

                header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
                print '<?xml version="1.0"?><gps>';
                while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        printf('<pos id="%s" stamp="%u" lat="%f" lon="%f" />',
                            $row['id'], $row['stamp'], $row['lat'], $row['lon']);
                }
                printf('<res val="%d" />', $res);

                print '</gps>';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                print 'Database problem: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

} else {
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        print '<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>Id: <input type="text" name="id" size=32 maxlength=32 /></p>
<p>Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" /></p>
<p>Longitude: <input type="text" name="lon" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
';

}

?>
```

I get the output which indicates that result is 0:

```
<gps>
<pos id="0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661" stamp="1287306960" lat="51.000000" lon="7.000000"/>
<pos id="0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661" stamp="1287323377" lat="51.000000" lon="7.000000"/>
<pos id="92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f" stamp="1287323381" lat="51.000000" lon="7.000000"/>
<pos id="92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f" stamp="1287323442" lat="51.300000" lon="7.000000"/>
<pos id="92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f" stamp="1287325610" lat="51.300000" lon="7.000000"/>
<pos id="92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f" stamp="1287325612" lat="51.300000" lon="7.000000"/>
<pos id="9dd4e461268c8034f5c8564e155c67a6" stamp="1287325692" lat="0.000000" lon="0.000000"/>
<res val="0"/>
</gps>
```

Regards, 
Alex

PS: Here is my current script, seems to work ok -

```
<?php

$id  = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
$lat = strtr(trim($_REQUEST['lat']), ',', '.');
$lng = strtr(trim($_REQUEST['lng']), ',', '.');

if (preg_match('/^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$/', $id) &&
    preg_match('/^[+-]?[0-9.]+$/', $lat) &&
    preg_match('/^[+-]?[0-9.]+$/', $lng)) {

        try {
                # enable persistent connections and throw exception on errors
                $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                                 PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);

                $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=/tmp dbname=snake', 'snake', 'snake', $options);

                #$db->exec('create table gps (id bytea check(length(id) = 16), stamp timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp, pos point not null)');

                $insert = $db->prepare("insert into gps (id, pos) values (decode(?, 'hex'), point(?, ?))");
                $insert->execute(array($id, $lat, $lng));

                $select = $db->prepare("select encode(id, 'hex') as id, extract('epoch' from stamp) as stamp, pos[0] as lat, pos[1] as lng from gps");
                $select->execute();

                header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
                print '<?xml version="1.0"?><gps>';
                while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        printf('<pos id="%s" stamp="%u" lat="%f" lng="%f" />',
                            $row['id'], $row['stamp'], $row['lat'], $row['lng']);
                }
                print '</gps>';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                print 'Database problem: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

} else {
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        print '<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>Id: <input type="text" name="id" size=32 maxlength=32 /></p>
<p>Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" /></p>
<p>Longitude: <input type="text" name="lng" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
';
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message at all? Are you using the same username form command line and from your script?

Comment: This isn't causing your problem, but I want to note this error.  In the digit match you have [0-9.], that dot (.) means "any character".  You'll want to escape it as [0-9\.] so it just matches a period.

Comment: @Conspicuous Metacharacters except `]\^-` are regular characters inside a character class, so this isn't a problem here.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Hrm, well, reading the manual in the past has suggested the opposite to me in the past. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html Note under "version 8 regular expressions" it talks about escaping in close proximity to character classes and doesn't point out such an exception.  But this one liner shows I'm wrong: perl -e '$foo = "0a9"; print "Dots are magic\n" if $foo =~ /^[0-9.]+$/;' -- No output.  Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: Yes, I'm a long time Perl user and I'm pretty sure, that you can use something like [-+0-9^.] in a regex char class. For example: perl -e 'print ("^" =~ /[-+0-9^.]/)' But thanks for looking at my code anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to do `PDOStatement->insert()` using an array of parameters, not multiple arguments:

```
$res = $insert->execute($id, array($lat, $lon));
```

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Comment: That was it, thank you! Strange that an exception wasn't thrown

Comment: There's a comment on [the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php#71281): "setting the PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE attribute to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION worked for me only with Mysql 4.x - I took me some time to figure this out ;-)"  Maybe that's the reason?